# Why can't I gift an item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-comes-alive

I have tried to download Minecraft Comes Alive from the actual website, but whenever I try gifting an item (like a Golden Apple) to a villager by pressing <kbd>g</kbd>, nothing happens.

Comment: Gift what? The game, or an object *in* the game? Press 'g' where?

Comment: I tried gifting a villager and it tells me press g and I do and nothing happens I try to gift them a golden apple and nothing happens

Comment: And you are sure MCA is installed properly?

Comment: I have forge and I have downloaded it the same way before and it worked but I recently had to delete my mods so I downloaded them again and now it does not seem to work.

Comment: Have you verified that the mod actually works? What about the keybind, does it appear in the settings?

Comment: it does not appear but i can talk with them and do other stuff just not gift.